# Code coverage page reference method

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, pagereference, code

Hi am new to salesforce , how to do code coverage for this class - page reference method is written.
below is the code:

```
public with sharing class AttachmentController {
    public Attachment attachObj {get;set;}

    public AttachmentController(){
        attachObj = new Attachment();
    }

    public PageReference saveAttachment() {
        attachObj.ParentId = 'a0c410000055VT5AAM'; //  parent record id for an Attachment
        try {
            insert attachObj;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        } 

        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment uploaded successfully'));
        return null; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample test method structure is given below. You can use a similar structure.

```
/**
 * Test Sample Page
 */
@isTest static void testSamplePage() {
    // TODO Set up the initial data needed for the test

    Test.startTest();

        PageReference pageRef = Page.<<Page Name>>; // TODO Give the Page of the Controller
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);    

        // TODO Verify the Logic 
        AttachmentController ctrl = new AttachmentController();

        // TODO Assert Statements to Validate Behaviour
        System.assert(ctrl.saveAttachment() == null);   

    Test.stopTest();

}
```